# Can I use app1 to update app2's datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two gae app like http://app1.appspot.com and http:://app2.appspot.com

Can I use app1 to update app2's datastore?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  That would be troublesome.  You could send a POST to a url at the other app, with secret key etc for protection, and the script for that url could update its data.